# no me responde el Formulario de inicio de sesión desplegable

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tengo un problema con mi  mi formulario desplegable con el **boton login** :
una ves que yo le coloco en el css a `arrow-up` y `login-form  display:nome;`
no me responde el boton el cual deberia de  desplegarse un formulario.

¿ Como soluciono esto ?

*Gracias*

```js
  <!-- animacion para recargar la paguina -->
  
   //la barra 
   window.sr= ScrollReveal();
   sr.reveal('.navbar',{

    durantion:5000,//tipo de transicion  de la barra por segundo
    origin: 'bottom'
   }); 
   // todo
   sr.reveal('.centralizar',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'top' ,
    overflow:0.3 //transiscion

   });
   // S.M.A.R.T.   
   sr.reveal('.City',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'top' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });

   //bton
   sr.reveal('.header-btn',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'top' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });
   //h3 (S.M.A.R.T.)
   sr.reveal('#h3',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'top' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });
   //slider 1 
   sr.reveal('#carousel-home',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'left' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });
   //slider2
   sr.reveal('#carouselExampleIndicators',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'left' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });
   //slider3
   sr.reveal('.carousel-indicators',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'left' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });
   //video 
   sr.reveal('.header-content-left',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'right' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });
   //slider 4
   sr.reveal('#carousel-inicio',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'right' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });
   //fron de sesion
   sr.reveal('.parent',{
    durantion:40000 ,
    origin:'right' ,
    overflow:0.3,
    delay: 500 ,

   });

  // Smooth scrolling
   document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
              behavior: 'smooth'
          });
      });
  }); 
    

       $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#box').addClass('show');
    });

    $('#reset').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#box').removeClass('show');
});

    //(inicio para la funcion de la transicion de inicio de sesion!)
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var arrow=$(".arrow-up");
   var form =$(".login-form");
   var status= false;
   $("#login").click(function(event){
    /* Act on the event */
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if (status==false) {
     arrow.fadeIn();
     form.fadeIn();
     status=true;
    }else{
     arrow.fadeOut();
     form.fadeOut();
     status=false;
    }

   }) 

  })
```

```css
.estructura{

          }
          .body {
           background-color: orange;
          }
       #menu_primero ul {
         list-style-type: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 20px;
         overflow: hidden;
         background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
      text-decoration: none;
     }
    li {
         float: left;
     }
    li a {
         display: block;
         color: white;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 30px;
         text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover {
         background-color: #111111;
    }

    .city {
         background-color: Orange;
         
         padding: 50px;
         
         font-size:10px;

    }



    .city1 {
         background-color: Orange;
         
         padding: 10px;
         
         font-size:10px;
    }
    .Foo {
         background-color: Orange;
         
         padding: 20px;
         
         font-size:20px;
    }
    .centralizar {
         text-align: Center;

    }

    .col h1 {
         color: white;
    }

    #h3{
          font-size:20
          color: black;
          text-align: Center; 
    }
    .navbar-brand{
      margin:0 ;
      padding:0;

    }
    .logo{
      height:50px ;
      padding-left:0px ;
      padding-right:100px ; 
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
      height: ;
      padding: ;

    }
    div .col-sm {
     /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    }
    
    /**/
    /* (INICIO!)clase del boton circular*/
    .btn-circle {
       width: 35px;
       height: 35px;
       
       padding: 0px 0px;
       font-size: 29px;
       line-height: 0;       
       border-radius: 20px;
       
    }
    
    /*---------------------------*/
    /*-----boton del slider (apliarlo)---*/
    .btn-lg {
        padding: 0.5rem 5rem;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: 1.3rem;
    }
    /*---------------------------*/
    .bg-light{
     background-color:orange; 
    }
    .cit {
         background-color: black;
         
         padding: 50px;
         
         font-size:10px;
      }
    .row{
     margin
     margin: 171px;
    }
    .div{
     width:100;
     height:90px;
    }
    /*icono de red social*/
    .icono{
     font-size:40px;     
     color:#ffff;
     padding-left:10px;
    } 
    /*--final de la red social!--*/ 
    /*--------- comienzo  grid-----------------*/
    .grid {
      
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: 400px repeat(2,400px); 
       grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 120px 120px);                    
       display:grid;
       grid-template-areas: "head head"
                            "menu main"
                            "foot foot";
                   /*Establece el tamaño de los huecos entre columnas (líneas verticales)*/
                   /*Establece el tamaño de los huecos entre filas (líneas horizontales).*/
       grid-column-gap: 30px;
         grid-row-gap: 10px;

         justify-content:center;
       align-content: stretch; 
        

         justify-items:stretch;
         height:500px ;
         align-items:stretch; 
         display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr;
       grid-template-rows: 2fr 3fr 1.90fr;
          
     }   
      
    .a { grid-area:head; }
    .b { grid-area:menu;}
    .c { grid-area:main;  }
    .d { grid-area:foot;  }

    /*------final grid -------*/    
    /*--------------------------*/
    /*------------prueba para scroll--------------*/

    #original {
     visibility: hidden; /*QUITAR PARA VER LA POSICIÓN REAL DE LOS ELEMENTOS*/
    }
    #copia {
     position: fixed; 
     height: auto; width: 100vw; 
     transition: top 1500ms cubic-bezier(.5,.33,.3,.9) 200ms; 
    }
    /*esta clase es para el fondo  de marca de agua!*/
    .ci {
         background-color: Orange;
         
         padding: 50px;
         
         font-size:10px;
      }
    
    #posic{
     padding-left: 600px;
     font-size:800%; 
    }
    /*----------final scroll----------------*/
    /* ----------video--------*/
    /* Podemos eliminar este estilo si no queremos que se adapte al ancho máximo */
    .delimitador{
          width:660px;    /* Ancho máximo */
          margin:auto;    /* Centramos el vídeo */
          
      }
      /* El contenedor con el padding-top crea el tamaño del vídeo */
    .contenedor{
          height:100%;
          width:100%;
          padding-top:60%; /* Relación: 16/9 = 56.25% */
          position:relative;
         
      }
      /* El iframe se adapta al tamaño del contenedor */
    .contenedor iframe{
          position:absolute;
          height:100%;
          width:100%;
          top:0px;
          left:0px;

      }
    /*-----------final del video-------------------*/ 

    /*estilo para el inicio de sesion del boton ingresar*/
    /*.parent {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;

    }

    #box {
        background-image:url(img/MARCADEAGUA.jpg); ;
        display: block;
        width: 350px;
        height: 135px;
        position: relative;        
        left: 885px;
        right: 10px;
        border-radius:2px;
        border-bottom: 5px solid orange;

    }
    

    .hidden {
          margin-top: -120px;
    }

    @keyframes SlideDown {
      from {
        margin-top: -120px;
      }
      to {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
    }

    .show {
      animation: SlideDown 1s ease-in;
      margin-top: 66px;
    }*/
    /*este estilo   colocando un triangulo para el boton inicio de sesion*/
    .arrow-up{
     width:0;
     height:0;
     position: absolute;
     border-left: 20px solid transparent;
     border-right : 20px solid transparent;
     border-bottom:20px solid #fff;
     right: 395px;
     /*display: none;*/
     }
    /*cuadro*/ 
    .login-form{
     position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:auto;
     background:#fff;
     right: 235px;
        top: 66px;
        border-radius:4px;
        border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
        background-image:url(img/MARCADEAGUA.jpg); 
        /*display: none;*/
    }
    /*dando forma al recuadro*/
    .login-form>form{
     width: 250px;
     margin: 25px auto;
     font-size:17px;
     font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
     color:black;
     letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    }
    /*estilo a el campo de texto y el de contraseña de inicio de sesion!*/
     input[type="text"],
     input[type="password"]{
      width: 200px;
      height:30px;
      border:0px;
      outline:none ;
      margin-bottom:10px; 
      margin-top: 5px;
      font-family:'Titillium Web',sans-serif; 
     }
     
     
    /*final del estilo de boton ingresar!*/
    

    /*RESPONSIVE PARA TABLES Y TELEFONOS MODIFICACION DE TAMAÑO!.*/
    /*@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {*/
      /* Para tables: */
       /*.main {
        width: 80%;
        padding: 0;
       }
       .right {
        width: 100%;
       }
    }*/
    /*@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {*/
      /* para telefono moviles.! : */
     /* .menu, .main, .right {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>no</title>
        <!-- google font (estilo de letra para la pag !)-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
         <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--Estilos personalizados-->       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        
        
  <!-- scroll Reavel (para la animacion del la pag al cargar )-->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
  <!-- fontawesome  icono de red social!-->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- animacion del inicio sesion -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      



      <!--barra lateral-->
       
    </head>
    <body>
     <!---************BARRA DE BUSCADOR***************-->
        
         <section id="home" >         
          <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-warning fixed-top">           
        <div class="container" >         
             <img src="" class="img-responsive logo" height="350" width="350"></img>
          <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>-->
        <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02" >-->
            <!--<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">-->
              <ul class="nav justify-content-end" >
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a  class="nav-link active; btn btn-warning" style="color: white;"  href="#home">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a  class="nav-link; btn btn-warning" style=" color: white"  href="#Noticias">Noticias</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a  class="nav-link; btn btn-warning" style="color: white;"href="#" target="_black" id="login">LOGIN</a>
              <div class="arrow-up "></div>
              <div class="login-form">
              <form>
               <label>Usuario</label>
               <div>
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Usuario" required> 
               </div>
               <label>Contraseña</label>    
               <div>                
                <input type="password"  placeholder="Contraseña" required> 
               </div>
               <div >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-md">Iniciar</button>    
                <a class="btn btn-warning" role="button" >Registar</a> 
             
                  </div>            
              </form>
              </div>
            </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled; btn btn-warning" style="color: white;" href="#Contacto">Contacto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a  class="nav-link disabled; btn btn-warning" style="color: white;"  href="#">no</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled; btn btn-success"   href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <!--icono de iniciar sesion!-->
            <!--<li  style=" padding-left: 1em">
             <a href="#"   class="btn btn-circle "><img src="img/ICONO inicio sesion.png" class="btn btn-circle"></span></a>--> 
            </li>
          </ul>          
          </div>  
            </form>
             
       </nav>              
      </section>
      <!--comiendo inicio front inicio de sesion-->
      <div class="parent ">
        <div id="box" class="hidden">                    
          <form class="form-inline">                     
           <div class="col-md">
             <label for="validationDefault01">First name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md">
            <label for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
          </form> 
        </div>
       </div> 
    
               
               
          
        

   
     <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
     
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Reorganiza tu código para que se pueda trabajar sobre él ?

Comment: soy nuevo en esto

Comment: edit y pusas el botn `editar este fragmento de código`

Comment: No he entendido el problema, ¿que formulario tendría que aparecer y que botón lo activa?

Comment: ya resolvi el problema :), tenia dos <script> iguales que no dejaba hacer la funcion que queria , que cuando se le daba click aun boton se me desplegara un formulario!